# How to align dropdown sub menu?

Tags: html, css

Here I made [JSFiddle demo of a small dropdown menu](http://jsfiddle.net/abLyH/)¹, but I only can't figure how to aligh dropdown sub menu box.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li> <a href="#" class="main-menu">vcdsfds</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">vcdsfds</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Depiction of where I want dropdown to be:

[image]

¹ original dropdown source: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: You mean the text or the drop down box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#nav li:hover ul {
    left: -50%;
}` Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/abLyH/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}
```

You can add margin... Maybe not best solution, but it works 
Example : [http://jsfiddle.net/abLyH/](http://jsfiddle.net/abLyH/16/)

Comment: sorry, forget to click on button Update :)

Answer (score 1):

if i had understand your problem, you must set the margin-left to your sub menu.

```
.sub-menu {
    margin-left : -50%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-align:center;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ5Ns/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
http://jsfiddle.net/abLyH/10/

I've added `ul` to container `<div>`

Comment: Check your fiddle demo, may be you missed something .

Comment: yes maybe n1kkou has right answer for it i guess ;) i misunderstood the question :p